# Have ol inside a li without having li being shown

Tags: html

I would like to have the following layout:

```
1. some data
2. some data
3. some data
   i. another data
   ii. another data
```

I use the following html:

```
<ol type="a">
Data
<li>some data</li>
<li>some data</li>
<li>some data:</li>
<ol type="i">
    <li>another data</li>
    <li>
        other data,
    </li>
</ol>
```

However, it gives a warning ol can't be inside li. If I add another li I get following output:

```
<ol type="a">
Data
<li>some data</li>
<li>some data</li>
<li>some data:</li>
<li>
<ol type="i">
    <li>another data</li>
    <li>
        other data,
    </li>
</ol>
</li>
</ol>


1. some data
2. some data
3. some data
4. 
   i. another data
   ii. another data
```

How to avoid the warning and still achieve the result. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should put your `ol` in the same `li` you want your list to be nested in. Here is an example:

```html
<ol type="a">
  <li>some data</li>
  <li>some data</li>
  <li>some data:
    <ol type="i">
      <li>another data</li>
      <li>other data,</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: this doesnt workfor me.

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong, I created a snippet from their code and it works.

Comment: thanks. I have this code. this creates a warning ol cant be inside another li and fails the html validator

Answer (score 0):

```html
<ol type="a">
  <li>some data</li>
  <li>some data</li>
  <li>
    <div>some data:</div>
    <ol type="i">
      <li>another data</li>
      <li>other data</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

We can use the following CSS to style the list items:

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ol[type="a"] li {
  counter-increment: list-a;
}

ol[type="a"] li::before {
  content: counter(list-a) ". ";
}

ol[type="a"] li > div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

ol[type="i"] li {
  counter-increment: list-i;
}

ol[type="i"] li::before {
  content: "(" counter(list-i) ") ";
}
```

This way, have a clean structure, and the CSS styling takes care of the numbering and formatting.

Comment: is it possible to add a class. i dont want to apply sitewide but only for this scenario. thanks